# iOS 8: Storage Provider extension allow for importing photos? Could it allow for photos to get inserted into iMessage?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

The documentation for the `Storage Provider` extension only refers to documents and files. It's not clear if it works for images and photographs. For instance, could an app create an extension that gets invoked in iMessage when the user taps the camera icon to insert a picture from the `Photo Gallery`?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how Apple implements the iMessage photo picker. If they go through the document picker API, you will get a chance to provide images. If the use the photo picker view controllers, however (PhotoUI framework or otherwise), you will not be able to.

Apple is most likely to go through the second route, but if this is an important feature for you, make sure to file a an enhancement request with Apple and post the radar number here so people can duplicate.

As of beta 2, Apple does not use the document picker API, so you will not be able to add your own data source for images if the Messages app does not change.